# popover position and arrow inside tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popover

How does one change where the arrow points from as well as the position of the popover inside a tableview cell?

heres what i have so far

```
    else if segue.identifier == "openingHours" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController
        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
        let controller = vc.popoverPresentationController
        if controller != nil {
            controller?.delegate = self
        }

    }
```

As you can see the popover appears in the top corner of the cell. I want the popover to appear below the blue view containing text "Arrow from below" with the arrow pointing towards the view
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too late out. But if someone else stumbles upon this question:

### Solution

It is based on setting the anchor for the `UIPopoverController` programmatically. You still need to assign it to something (for example the "view") in storyboards if you are using storyboards, but the code will override that choice.

This can be performed rather simply by applying the following to your `prepare(for: sender:)` and also add the desired view the `UIPopoverController` should anchor to in the sender parameter of `performSegue(withIdentifier: , sender:)`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    else if segue.identifier == "openingHours" {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController

        vc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
        vc?.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
            // Remember to pass in the cell or whatever view you want it to be anchored to in performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueID", sender: tableViewCell)
            if let anchorView = sender as? UIView {
                vc?.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = anchorView
            }
            // If you want to anchor it to a UIBarButtonItem (in a nav bar for example use this), remove the code bellow if you are using a view: 
            else if let anchorView = sender as? UIBarButtonItem {
                vc?.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = anchorView
            }


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to drag from  the anchor icon in the Attributes Inspector of the seque:
[image]

Comment: You can't do this with a tableview.  The anchor has to be attached to the tableview rather than whats inside the cell.

Comment: Hi, OK try to make an invisible button in the cell and use that as the ancher! That should be possible.